# Propagating mouse events from clickable Google Maps overlays

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events

Is it possible to have an overlay in a Google map (circle, polygon, etc.) that is clickable, but still propagates mouse events down to the underlying map? Currently it seems like for instance a clickable circle will always hide the events from the map.

Example: Here I would like both click handlers to fire when you click the circle: http://jsfiddle.net/tW9SE/

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    center: center,
    radius: 100000,
    clickable: true
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(){
    alert("Map clicked");
});

google.maps.event.addListener(circle, "click", function(){
    alert("Circle clicked");
});
```

I cannot find a property on the overlay that allows for event propagation, except from setting clickable=false, and thereby disable event handlers on the overlay itself.

Comment: On circle click, can't you trigger a map click?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just trigger the click yourself:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(circle, "click", function(){
    alert("Circle clicked");
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click', null);
});
```

More info in [Marcelo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438154/7469) about programmatically triggering clicks on a Google map.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right that this would be the default way of doing it, as long as the API does not have a "enableEventPropagation" option. But I am thinking that I would need to handle this on a more general level, and then I would need to do this for each and every event (mousemove, click, rightclick, etc). And also if there are other overlays between the map and the circle, I would need to handle event propagation to those as well. Just seems like a hassle, if you understand.. Would be nice to be able to let the events pass through the layers. But that is maybe not possible?

Comment: It would depend on how the layers are built. Layers z-indexed on top of each other aren't necessarily nested in the DOM, so standard event bubbling likely doesn't apply.

Comment: Good point. It seems your solution is the best one then. Thank you!